# How to load image into oracle database table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

How to load image into oracle  database table

suppose i have a table like image

```
CREATE TABLE image (img_id number
                  ,img_name varchar2(100)
                  ,img   BLOB) ;
```

can any one help me out

Comment: where are the images? Filesystem/Database/Java object

Comment: Robert Merkwürdigeliebe images in filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see robert's answer for the approach if the files are on the DB server.

If the files are on the CLIENT filesystem, use SQLLDR. for example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  2    id number primary key,
  3    image      BLOB
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> host sqlldr user/pass@yourdb control=load_image.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Nov 29 10:41:08 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1

SQL> select * from tab1;

        ID
----------
IMAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
FFD8FFE000104A46494600010101004800480000FFE111C44578696600004D4D002A00000008000B
010F00020000000100000000011000020000000100000000011200030000000100010000011A0005


SQL> select length(image) from tab1;

LENGTH(IMAGE)
-------------
       263508

SQL>
```

where the control file is like this:

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'images.txt'
INTO TABLE tab1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(id  ,
 image_filename    FILLER CHAR(100),
 image             LOBFILE(image_filename) TERMINATED BY EOF)
```

and a sample images.txt file:

```
1,foo.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY test_dir AS 'C:\'; 

DECLARE
  l_bfile  BFILE;
  l_blob   BLOB;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tab1 (col1, col2)
  VALUES (empty_blob(), 'test1')
  RETURN col1 INTO l_blob;

  l_bfile := BFILENAME('test_dir', 'Test.txt');
  DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, Dbms_Lob.File_Readonly);
  DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_blob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
  DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe the update is superfluous. the lob pointer is returned in write mode with the technique mr dump did.

Comment: OK cool. I'll check it out, not that I don't believe you ... ;-)

Comment: DazzaL After creating DIRECTORY how can we place files in that

Comment: If image files are in DB server . we need to create directory ,so can any one tell me where will it create after executing 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY test_dir AS 'C:\'; ' and how we place files in that directory please let me know